# How to use EdiTools library for converting XML data to EDI format in C#

Tags: c#, edi, edifact

Currently I am looking for any EDIFACT package so that I can convert an XML data packet to EDIFACT.
I did't find any package, after soo many finding I have found 'editools' package.
Github repo link : [Editools](https://github.com/davidpeng/editools). How can I convert xml to edi using editools package. And can anyone help me to understand the EDI file format.

```
var isa = new EdiSegment("ISA");
            isa[01] = "00";
            isa[02] = "".PadRight(10);
            isa[03] = "00";
            isa[04] = "".PadRight(10);
            isa[05] = "ZZ";
            isa[06] = "SENDER".PadRight(15);
            isa[07] = "ZZ";
            isa[08] = "RECEIVER".PadRight(15);
            isa[09] = EdiValue.Date(6, DateTime.Now);
            isa[10] = EdiValue.Time(4, DateTime.Now);
            isa[11] = "U";
            isa[12] = "00400";
            isa[13] = 1.ToString("d9");
            isa[14] = "0";
            isa[15] = "P";
            isa[16] = ">";
            ediDocument.Segments.Add(isa);
            var gs = new EdiSegment("GS");
            gs[01] = "PO";
            gs[02] = "SENDER";
            gs[03] = "RECEIVER";
            gs[04] = EdiValue.Date(8, DateTime.Now);
            gs[05] = EdiValue.Time(4, DateTime.Now);
            gs[06] = EdiValue.Numeric(0, 1);
            gs[07] = "X";
            gs[08] = "004010";
            ediDocument.Segments.Add(gs);
```

What is this written here...

I try this below lines of code, but I did't understand the code

```
var ediDocument = EdiDocument.LoadXml("xmlData.xml");

            var isa = new EdiSegment("ISA");
            isa[01] = "00";
            isa[02] = "".PadRight(10);
            isa[03] = "00";
            isa[04] = "".PadRight(10);
            isa[05] = "ZZ";
            isa[06] = "SENDER".PadRight(15);
            isa[07] = "ZZ";
            isa[08] = "RECEIVER".PadRight(15);
            isa[09] = EdiValue.Date(6, DateTime.Now);
            isa[10] = EdiValue.Time(4, DateTime.Now);
            isa[11] = "U";
            isa[12] = "00400";
            isa[13] = 1.ToString("d9");
            isa[14] = "0";
            isa[15] = "P";
            isa[16] = ">";
            ediDocument.Segments.Add(isa);
            var gs = new EdiSegment("GS");
            gs[01] = "PO";
            gs[02] = "SENDER";
            gs[03] = "RECEIVER";
            gs[04] = EdiValue.Date(8, DateTime.Now);
            gs[05] = EdiValue.Time(4, DateTime.Now);
            gs[06] = EdiValue.Numeric(0, 1);
            gs[07] = "X";
            gs[08] = "004010";
            ediDocument.Segments.Add(gs);

            // more segments...

            ediDocument.Options.SegmentTerminator = '~';
            ediDocument.Options.ElementSeparator = '*';
            ediDocument.Save("save.txt");
```

Please help me to understand this code or EDI file format.

Comment: That structure is ANSI X12, not EDIFACT.   So you're looking to translate an XML file into outbound EDIFACT to send to your partner.  EDIFAbric might help here, or EDIDEV

Comment: hay @Andrew thanks for comment. Can you please help me to convert xml data packet to EDIFACT D960A format. There is no tools or any documentation in the community. EdiFabric is paid tool, I want any open source tools. Thanks.

Comment: BOTS - it's an open source Python translator.  The only open source one I know of.  https://bots.readthedocs.io/en/latest/